# How to access archive.ubuntu.com from an IPv6 only machine?

Tags: package-management, updates, ipv6

Because [archive.ubuntu.com](http://archive.ubuntu.com) hasn't any IPv6 endpoints, an IPv6-only Ubuntu machine is quite unusable: no package management, no updates, etc.

Is there any way to overcome this problem without enabling IPv4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main archive server, and many mirrors don't support IPv6 so going IPv6 only is very cutting edge of you but... most of the rest of humanity probably will join you when we are well into 2012 (if not 2015) or when it becomes really unavoidable.

That being said...

1. I found a link from [2008](http://www.linux-archive.org/ubuntu-user/89207-upgrading-ipv6-only-host.html) that states you can use [a gateway from sixxs.net](http://www.sixxs.net/tools/gateway/) 
   From the link:

   > Edit your `sources.list` and replace `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` by `http://archive.ubuntu.com.ipv6.sixxs.org/ubuntu/`

   Looking at the website this looks like it is still working.
2. Some mirrors are IPv6-ready (the ones operated by BIT). Their URLs are...

   - nl.archive.ubuntu.com / ubuntuarchive.bit.nl
   - ftp.belnet.be (BelNet)
   - ie.archive.ubuntu.com / ubuntu.ftp.heanet.ie (HeaNet).
   - mirrors.xmission.com (operated by Xmission)

So the answer is yes you can do it w/o IPv4 but why not use both IPv4 and IPv6 like everyone else does that uses IPv6?

Comment: thanks! why i wanted to go ipv6 only is because ipv4 addresses are a lot more expansive at my cloud provider, and with many servers it adds up..

Comment: I would also point out that mirrors.xmission.com is IPv6 enabled. IPv6 didn't work for a while, but I talked to them and they fixed it.

Comment: So much for the rest of humanity joining us well into 2015 :( us.archive.ubuntu.com still hates me....

Comment: greetings from 2023. You won't believe me but...

Comment: @VitaliiKorsakov don't hold you breath yet but we are almost out of IPv4 addresses ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind yeah, after 25 years of IPv6 implementation

Answer (score 0):

situation became better in recent years.
here is a choice that should work most time:

mirrors.up.pt

ftp.rezopole.net (FR)

ubuntu.lagis.at

ubuntu.unitedcolo.de

mirror.dataone.nl

ubuntu.inode.at

mirror.init7.net

mirror.unix-solutions.be

mirrors.layeronline.com (CDN)

mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn

ubuntu.univ-reims.fr